# How to use Docker link in Ansible when link var defined

Tags: docker, ansible

I want playbook that will start an container (in a task) and only link it to another container if the link is provided in a variable. For example:

```
- name: Start container
  docker_container:
    image: somerepo/app-server:{{ var_tag }}
    name: odoo-server
    state: started
    log_opt: "tag=app-server-{{ var_tag }}"
    expose:
      - 8080
    links:
      - "{{ var_db_link }}"
        when: var_db_link is defined
```

But of course this does not work.  (I know `-` without a value is invalid ~ this is just pseudo code)

The whole task is actually quite a bit larger because it includes other directives so I really don't to have 2 versions of the task defined, one for starting with a link and another without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when use '-',  it means there is certain value , so I have a way to avoid it.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Start container
      docker_container:
        image: centos 
        name: odoo-server
        state: started
        expose:
          - 8080
        links: "{{ var_db_link | default([]) }}"
```

then test it use

```
ansible-playbook  ha.yml -e var_db_link="redis-master:centos"
ansible-playbook  ha.yml
```

It runs normally!

Comment: Great! I noted that it does not work for `etc_hosts` because it expects a dictionary and not a list so for that I use: `etc_hosts: "{{ var_etc_hosts | default({}) }}"`